# If statement inside a function won't run for some reason

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a function where when i click a div it grabs the div's first class, and then through a series of if statements, determines which dropdown to show, and i cannot for the life of me figure out why this wont work?

the divs each has a unique class "Tab1", "Tab2"... as well as a shared class "headerTab"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dropdown').hide();

    $(".headerTab").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        var clicked = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

        if (clicked == "Tab1") {
            $('.dropdown1').show();
        };

        else if (clicked == "voresVisionTab") {
            $('.dropdown2').show();
        };

        else (clicked == "Tab2") {
            $('.dropdown3').show();
        };

        else (clicked == "Tab3") {
            $('.dropdown4').show();
        };
    });
});
```

If i remove the if statements then the code runs fine, i hope you guys can help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the semicolons after the closing braces and make the previous-to-last statement an `else if`, otherwise the code is syntactically invalid and obviously won't work. Other than that, you should use a `switch` (or even better, a map) in such situations and additionally it's not a very good idea to be dependent on the order of classes.

Comment: You have two else, it's not possible.. And with else, you can't write ()

Comment: For goodness sake use a `switch` for simple multi-value comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others you have broken your if statements with ";"s.

Use a switch for simple multi-value cases like yours:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dropdown').hide();

    $(".headerTab").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        var clicked = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

        switch (clicked)
        {
           case "Tab1":
               $('.dropdown1').show();
               break;

           case "voresVisionTab":
              $('.dropdown2').show();
              break;

           case "Tab2":
              $('.dropdown3').show();
              break;

           case "Tab3":
              $('.dropdown4').show();
              break;
        }
    });
});
```

This is much easier to read and maintain.

### My real-world suggestion

In this instance I would suggest you put your `.dropdown1` selectors inside `data-` attributes on the clicked items, then all that code is not needed in the first place!

```
    $(".headerTab").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        $($this).data('target')).show();
    });
```

And your `headerTab` links would simply have `data-target=".dropdown1"` etc on them. Now two lines of code instead of dozens and no code maintenance issues as it is now data-driven.

*note: `.data('target')` is just a handy shorthand for `.attr('data-target')`*

Comment: `.data('target')` and `.attr('data-target')` are not completely interchangeable. If you use `.data('target',newvalue)` to modify the stored value, it won't be reflected in the DOM attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yDPF5/

Comment: While Blazemonger's comment is correct, at no point did I mention the setter methods. The getter methods are equivalent (and `data` is 5 characters shorter).

Comment: Yes, of course. My comment was intended for posterity (as well as your own information).  `.data('str')` is not simply shorthand for `.attr('data-str')`; they are in fact performing fundamentally different actions which only appear identical in some cases. (For instance, `.attr()` always returns a string while `.data()` will attempt to convert it into a number, Boolean or object first.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (clicked == "Tab1") {
    $('.dropdown1').show();
} else if (clicked == "voresVisionTab") {
    $('.dropdown2').show();
} else if (clicked == "Tab2") {
    $('.dropdown3').show();
} else if (clicked == "Tab3") {
   $('.dropdown4').show();
};
```

You had `;` after your if's and else's and needed else ifs where you had only elses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write two `else`. And else haven't condition.

```
$('.dropdown').hide();

    $(".headerTab").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        var clicked = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

        if (clicked == "Tab1") {
            $('.dropdown1').show();
        };

        else if (clicked == "voresVisionTab") {
            $('.dropdown2').show();
        };

        else if(clicked == "Tab2") {
              ^
            $('.dropdown3').show();
        };

        else if(clicked == "Tab3") {
              ^
            $('.dropdown4').show();
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you split the string containing classes, which makes it into an array. So if your class isn't the first in order of the classes. your if statement won't compare the right class.
Second you got syntax wrong on the if-cases.

Try the following:

```
$('.headerTab').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
    $(".dropdown").hide();

    if ($this.hasClass('Tab1')) {
        $('.dropdown1').show();
    } else if ($this.hasClass('voresVisionTab')) {
        $('.dropdown2').show();
    } else if ($this.hasClass('Tab2')) {
        $('.dropdown3').show();
    } else ($this.hasClass('Tab3')) {
        $('.dropdown4').show();
    }
});
```

Edit: I would give each headerTab a unique ID (or a data-property), then check for which one the clicked on has and compare it with a switch-case instead of a if.